# How can I define a new language?

Tags: listings, sourcecode

i need to insert code into my document which is written in ST (structured text) (PLL language). Couldn't find any existing solution in the web.

How to add the language to the package to use it?

---

Edit: A little bit of syntax as example

```
SUPER^();

CASE _iState OF
0:  
    IF SUPER^.init() THEN
        _iState := 1;
    END_IF
1:  
    _iState := 10;  
END_CASE

VAR CONSTANT
    (*
      comment
    *)
    var         : BYTE := 2#11111110;
END_VAR
```

Any possibility or other suggestions to add this kind of sourecode in my document to describe it?

Comment: Is your language (or one with a similar syntax) in the list of this document? [Language, Style and Format drivers for Listings](ftp://ftp.rrzn.uni-hannover.de/pub/mirror/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/listings/lstdrvrs.pdf)

Comment: What syntactic elements do you want to highlight and how?